# How to translate django-oscar's dashboard?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have installed django-oscar (ecommerce) today and have faced the following problem: 
it looks like I am only able to translate the names of the models in `/admin` section, and not anything else. 
That's what I have in my configuration:

```
#settings.py
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Minsk'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'be'
LOCALE_PATHS = (
'/home/beardy/work/fireshop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/locale',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

What I am doing: 
1) running `django-admin.py makemessages --locale=be` in `/home/beardy/work/fireshop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar` 
the django.po file is being generated in the `oscar/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES` directory 
2) edit translations in django.po 
3) then I run `django-admin.py compilemessages` 
4) server restart

Looks like everything is done according to the documentation. 
Still, nothing in the dashboard gets translated, only model names in `/admin`. 
What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Oscar 0.5 you should follow info on their [read the docs](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-0.5/howto/how_do_i_translate_oscar.html?highlight=localization) site.

What you could try on first look here is:
Define locale folder inside your project and not in site-packages/oscar generate them there and be sure to set

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('be', _('Belarusian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

inside settings for oscars language dropdown.